# Navigation drawer hanged for 2 seconds while selecting one option

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in which i have many fragments which come on selecting any item of navigation drawer. On one item I am showing a map. I don't know why on selecting that item navigation drawer hangs for 2-3 seconds and then drawer close. I want it smooth like other items in navigation drawer.

Here is my code for navigation drawer in MainActivity:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();



            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

And here is the code of fragment on which the drawer hangs:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);
    mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner 
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnFind;

        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = ( Button ) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_find);


        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());


        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { 
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = 
                    (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                    onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
                         }      
         return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Try putting the  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList); above the switch statement.  if(mDrawerLayout != null)mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);  Let me know it that does anything?

Comment: No i tried as you suggested but same result. I tried a little bit of research and i found that in fragment if i comment rest of the code other than   mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();  it is working smooth . And if i uncomment everything, it is hanged again

Comment: Okay so if you comment out /* your code within the View rootView and the return  */  does it still hang?

Comment: Yes if i comment everything inside  View rootView and the return, it is still getting hanged :(

Comment: Damn Hulk.  It is not doing it with any of the other fragments?

Comment: No , it is working perfectly with other fragments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74606/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-hulk).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced problem like that.
That totally work for me. Hope will help you

In your code,

In **displayView** function, put all codes in Runnable.

```
mPendingThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             //Here is all your code
             switch(position){
             .........
             .........
        }
    };
```

In **onCreate** method,

```
    mHandler = new Handler();

// Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            if (mPendingThread != null) {
                mHandler.post(mPendingThread);
                mPendingThread = null;
            }

        }

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: can you edit this in my code? Havnt used runnable before. Please

Comment: Nothing is working now. I put the code of switch in runnable but i am getting white screen on all clicks

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot some codes since it was been too long. I will edit now